# How to delete specific running docker containers in batch

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to run more than 70 docker containers at once. Later, these containers need to be stopped.

At the moment I can `docker stop` all of them with the shell command `docker stop $(docker ps -f since=<last docker before>)`. It works OK, but if there are any containers started after mine, I have a problem as the above code will stop them too.

Is there any way I can close all of running containers with some kind of specific search?

I know there is an `docker ps -f label=<some label>`, but I just haven't figured out on how to use it yet.

Comment: Using that label is the correct way to do it. Can you share more about the images you are running? Are they all instances of the same image or are they different?

Comment: I used label and got ir to work with the answer given! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're launching many containers at the same time, launch them all with

```sh
docker run --label=anyname other-docker-args-of-yours image:tag
```

And when you want to delete all your containers just do

```sh
docker stop $(docker ps -f label=anyname | awk 'NR>1 {print$1}')
```

where `anyname` is the label name you provide during the `docker run` command and
`awk 'NR>1 {print$1}'` ignores the column header `CONTAINER_ID` and just prints the values alone.

Edit-1:
I later realized that you can achieve the list of Container_ID without `awk` as well. I'd consider using the below line.

```sh
docker stop `docker ps -qaf label=anyname`
```

If you want to remove all stoppped containers also, then include `a` within the options, like instead of `-qf` use `-qaf`.
`-q` to print container IDs alone.
`-a` for all containers including stopped.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!
I guess I was using --label=anyname in the wrong part of docker run. But I added it right after "run", and everything works as it is supposed to!